# Can I create new goal in admin of GA using API

Tags: api, google-analytics, goal-tracking

So I know how to create new goal in Goals section of Google Analytics admin panel. 
I can do it by hands in web UI like on the pic below:
[GA admin UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u25L2.png)

My question - Is there a way to create it using API? So I want not inserting an event to existing goal (like described [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/goals/insert)) , but I want to set up new goal using API. Is it possible or google don't have such api method?

Comment: The link you have provided is just exactly about creating a new goal via API.

Comment: Thank you @kgrg, I find out you're right! I just didn't recognise it because there are not listed all properties in example. Like Category, Action, Label, Value.